# Pivot Dynamic row to Column with output parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot, row

There is no problem for me to pivot statistic columns in my query e.g Column 1 , Column 2 , Column 3.... and so on.

But i would like to do this dynamic instead.

My data looks like this:

[image]

i want to be able to EXECUTE a store procedure to get the output result:
**Exec sp_output 1** (from another window where '1' represents the PoolID (@AppPool)) to look like this:

[image]

This is my SP:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
@Query as nvarchar(100) -- OUTPUT?, 
@AppPool AS nvarchar(50) 
AS

SELECT @Query = Attribute  FROM [dbo].[Vy_UserAccess] WHERE PoolID = @AppPool

SELECT [Users],'+ @Query +' FROM
(SELECT [Pool],[Users],[RecNum],[Attribute],[Values] FROM [dbo].[Vy_UserAccess] ) AS  T1
PIVOT (MAX([Values]) FOR [ATTRIBUTE] IN ('+ @Query +')) AS T2
```

Is this possible to achieve by just fine tuning my code or do i have to go on another direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do It in following:

**QUERY**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
@AppPool AS NVARCHAR(60)
AS
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols += QUOTENAME([Name]) + ','
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Attribute as Name
        FROM    [dbo].[Vy_UserAccess]
        WHERE   PoolID = @AppPool
        ) a 
ORDER BY Name DESC 

SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)   

SET @sql    = 'SELECT Users, ' + @cols + ' FROM 
    (
    SELECT [Pool],[Users],[RecNum],[Attribute],[Values] 
    FROM [dbo].[Vy_UserAccess]
     ) AS  T1
PIVOT (MAX([Values]) FOR [ATTRIBUTE] IN ('+ @cols +')) AS T2'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@AppPool NVARCHAR(60)', @AppPool
```

**EXECUTION**

```
Exec sp_test 1
```

---

**QUERY WITH SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test 
@AppPool AS NVARCHAR(60)
AS

CREATE TABLE #test
(
    PoolId NVARCHAR(60),
    Pool NVARCHAR(40),
    Users NVARCHAR(60),
    RecNum INT,
    Attribute NVARCHAR(40),
    [Values] NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
('1', 'FINANCE', 'User1', 2, 'DIVISION', '010'),
('1', 'FINANCE', 'User1', 1, 'COMPANY',  '1'),
('1', 'FINANCE', 'User1', 1, 'DIVISION', '050')



DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols += QUOTENAME([Name]) + ','
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Attribute as Name
        FROM    #test
        WHERE   PoolID = @AppPool       
        ) a 
ORDER BY Name DESC                      
SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)


SET @sql    = 'SELECT Users, ' + @cols + ' FROM 
    (
    SELECT [Pool],[Users],[RecNum],[Attribute],[Values] 
    FROM #test
     ) AS  T1
PIVOT (MAX([Values]) FOR [ATTRIBUTE] IN ('+ @cols +')) AS T2'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql, N'@AppPool NVARCHAR(60)', @AppPool

DROP TABLE #test
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Users   DIVISION    COMPANY
User1   050         1
User1   010         NULL
```

Comment: where in the exec can i set what value i want to use for the AppPool?

Comment: @Nils You can execute It in following: `Exec sp_test 1`